# CKEditor 5 não funciona no Next.JS

Tags: react, ckeditor, next.js

Estou com o seguinte erro:

> Unhandled Runtime Error
> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
> Check the render method of `Resumos`.

Tentei duas formas diferentes que encontrei pra solucionar isso, mas nenhuma resolveu

Forma 1:

```js
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";

const { CKEditor } = dynamic(
  () => {
    return import('@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react');
  },
  { ssr: false }
);

const {ClassicEditor} = dynamic(
  () => {
    return import('@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic');
  },
  { ssr: false }
);

const Resumos = ({id}) => {
  <CKEditor 
       editor={ ClassicEditor }
       data={textoResumoAluno}
       onChange={handleChangeTextoResumoAluno}
  />
}
```

Forma 2:

```js
const Resumos = ({id}) => {
    const editorRef = useRef()
    const [ editorLoaded, setEditorLoaded ] = useState( false )
    const { CKEditor, ClassicEditor } = editorRef.current || {}

    useEffect( () => {
        editorRef.current = {
          CKEditor: require( '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react' ),
          ClassicEditor: require( '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic' )
        }
        setEditorLoaded( true )
    }, [] );


{editorLoaded ? ( 
      <CKEditor
           editor={ ClassicEditor }
           data={textoResumoAluno}
           onInit={ editor => { /*You can store the "editor" and use when it is needed.
                 console.log('Editor is ready to use!', editor)*/
            }}
           onChange={handleChangeTextoResumoAluno}
       /> 
  ) : (
          <div>Editor loading</div>
  )}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Também tive alguns problemas com o CKEditor no Next.js, no React era só importar e usar, mas como o Next.js renderiza a página no servidor antes de enviar para o Browser, ocorria alguns erros.

A forma que eu encontrei para resolver foi criar um Componente CustomEditor que contêm a importação do CKEditor e do ClassicEditor e depois importar esse componente usando o dynamic.

No meu caso eu não usei o ClassicEditor, mas uma versão customizada que eu gerei pelo site do CKEditor, usando a ferramenta [Online Build](https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-5/online-builder/).

Assim eu poderia usar outras formas de fazer o upload das imagens e usar outros componentes como o Bloco de Código.

Eu criei uma pasta chamada ckeditor5 dentro do projeto Next.js, extrai os arquivos dentro dela e executei o comando de instalação: npm add file:./ckeditor5

> Antes de executar o comando você pode editar o arquivo ckeditor5/package.json para escolher um outro nome, tipo "ckeditor5-inline", caso você precise instalar duas ou mais builds customizadas.

O componente CustomEditor ficou assim:

```
import Editor from 'ckeditor5-custom-build'
import { CKEditor } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react'

export default function CustomEditor({ data, onReady, onChange, onBlur, onFocus }) {

    const editorConfiguration = {/* Essa Configuração você Encontra no arquivo ckeditor5/srcckeditor.js no Objeto Editor.defaultConfig */}

    return (
        <CKEditor
            editor={Editor}
            config={editorConfiguration}
            data={data}
            onReady={onReady}
            onChange={onChange}
            onBlur={onBlur}
            onFocus={onFocus} />
    )
}
```

E a página do Editor ficou assim:

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'
import { useState } from 'react'

const CustomEditor = dynamic(() => import('../components/CustomEditor'), { ssr: false })

import styles from '../styles/Home.module.scss'

export default function Editor() {
    const [contents, setContents] = useState('')

    const handleReady = (editor) => {
        // console.log('onReady')
    }

    const handleChange = (event, editor) => {
        // console.log('onChange')
        const data = editor.getData()
        setContents(data)
    }

    const handleBlur = (event, editor) => {
        // console.log('onBlur')
    }

    const handleFocus = (event, editor) => {
        // console.log('onFocus')
    }

    return (
        <div className={styles.container}>
            <Head>
                <title>Custom CKEditor Next</title>
                <meta name="description" content="Custom CKEditor Next" />
                <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
            </Head>
            <h1>Custom CKEditor Next</h1>
            <CustomEditor data={contents} onReady={handleReady} onChange={handleChange} onBlur={handleBlur} onFocus={handleFocus} />
            <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: contents }} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Eu coloquei esse exemplo no meu GitHub, nesse link [Custom CKEditor Next](https://github.com/joaops/custom-ckeditor-next)

Espero que eu tenha ajudado.